# bxSlider breaking after show()

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider on ticker mode and have a pair of buttons that respectively hide and show it with

```
$('.bxslider').hide();
```

and

```
$('.bxslider').show();
```

and after show(), it does reappear, but it stops moving. The same thing happens if I try with any other divs it's contained in.

Playing with the CSS right on the example at  http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker, adding display:none and then changing it back to display:block, does the same thing, so it's something about bxSlider itself rather than a mistake I'm making, but is there a way I can make it work? Or else a good alternative to hiding it in the first place? I don't want it clickable, so opacity isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize slider on show().

```
$( ".bxslider" ).show( function() {
    slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings

Comment: Thank you!!! For the record, I didn't have "slider" defined, so I had to use the whole $('.bxslider').bxSlider({mode: 'horizontal'}) with my settings, but it worked!

Comment: Great! I'm glad that my answer helped you!